# Using navigation controller and ECSlidingViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, segue

If anyone is familiar with `ECSLidingViewController`, I'd really appreciate some help. Currently, I have set a static `UITableViewController` as my `underleftviewcontroller`. Within that, I have a cell that'd I'd like to push to another `UITableViewController` and make it the new `underleftviewcontroller`.

Regardless of using the `ECSlidingViewController` library, when I connect a static cell to push to another view, it isn't working. Any idea why?

I have tried embedding the `underleftviewcontroller` into a `UINavigationController` and then connecting the cell with the next UIView with a segue, but whenever I click it, it never pushes.

I have found a solution for creating a new `underleftviewcontroller`, but it is sans animation.

```
//This is what creates my new underLeftViewController.
self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventsMenu"];
```

It is connected to the cell in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

How do I either make a working `UINavigationController` or add animation to the transition of this cell to a new view (preferably a slide left and slide right transition)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was making my underLeftViewController the navigation controller instead of the Menu.

That way it loads the navigation controller then the menu.

Also helpful. If you have a UITableView in a nav controller and you don't want the nav bar visible on the main table, implement this in the view that you don't want the toolbar:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: May I ask ... When you do this and lets say you keep the navigation bar on the left menu. When you press "back", does the back animation successfully present?

Comment: i'm using EcSlidingViewController - what if you don't wish to hide the NavigationBar?